# Getting specific contact information

Tags: android, android-contacts

I'm trying to get the given name, family name etc of a specific contact on android but can't seem to be able to. I've been banging my head on this for hours, basically `if (nameCur.moveNext())` is always false! This code is originally by @perborin ([How to get the first name and last name from Android contacts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4301064/how-to-get-the-first-name-and-last-name-from-android-contacts)). Please help!

P.S. I've added `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>` in the AndroidManifest, so that is not the problem.

```
// A contact ID is fetched from ContactList
Uri resultUri = data.getData(); 
Cursor cont = getContentResolver().query(resultUri, null, null, null, null);
if (!cont.moveToNext()) {   
    Toast.makeText(this, "Cursor contains no data", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
                return;
}
int columnIndexForId = cont.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID);
String contactId = cont.getString(columnIndexForId);

// Fetch contact name with a specific ID
String whereName = ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " = ? AND " + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTACT_ID + " = " + contactId; 
String[] whereNameParams = new String[] { ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE };
Cursor nameCur = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, null, whereName, whereNameParams, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME);
while (nameCur.moveToNext()) {
    String given = nameCur.getString(nameCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME));
    String family = nameCur.getString(nameCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.FAMILY_NAME));
    String display = nameCur.getString(nameCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME));
    Toast.makeText(this, "Name: " + given + " Family: " +  family + " Displayname: "  + display, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
nameCur.close();
cont.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved by referring to user3717188 answer at [Get first and last name of a contact rather than single display name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8431897/get-first-and-last-name-of-a-contact-rather-than-single-display-name).

```
Cursor phone_cursor = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.
                Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
        while (phone_cursor.moveToNext()) {
            try {
            int id = Integer.parseInt(phone_cursor.getString(phone_cursor.getColumnIndex
                    (ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID)));
            Cursor name_cursor = cr.query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,null,
                    ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + "  = " + id, null, null);

                String name = phone_cursor.getString(phone_cursor.getColumnIndex
                        (ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
                String first_name ="";
                String last_name = "";
                while (name_cursor.moveToNext()) {
                    if(name_cursor.getString(name_cursor.getColumnIndex
                            (ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.FAMILY_NAME))!=null){
                    first_name = name_cursor.getString(name_cursor.getColumnIndex
                            (ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME));
                    last_name = name_cursor.getString(name_cursor.getColumnIndex
                            (ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.FAMILY_NAME));
                }}
                name_cursor.close();
                String phoneNumber = phone_cursor.getString(phone_cursor.getColumnIndex
                        (ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
        phone_cursor.close();
```