# Get contact name?

Tags: java, android, xml, database, android-intent

I want to get the contact name, but I'm not able to. After looking at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4301064/how-to-get-the-first-name-and-last-name-from-android-contacts), I tried to get the name using family, given, and display, but nothing worked

```
  @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == PICK_CONTACT && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Uri contactUri = data.getData();
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contactUri, null, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst(); //Move to first row...I actually dont know why this part is necessary, but I get an error without it... 
            int NumberColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER); //Int column is the column of the numbers
            int NameColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME);
            String contactNumber = cursor.getString(NumberColumn);
            String contactName = cursor.getString(NameColumn);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ""+ contactNumber +"" +contactName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
```

/

```
public void addContact(View v){ //OnClick listener to launch contact picker
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code for getting contact of specific  number

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_PICK_CONTACTS && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Response: " + data.toString());
        uriContact = data.getData();

        retrieveContactName();

    }
}

 private void retrieveContactName() {

        String contactName = null;

        // querying contact data store
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uriContact, null, null, null, null);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {

            // DISPLAY_NAME = The display name for the contact.
            // HAS_PHONE_NUMBER =   An indicator of whether this contact has at least one phone number.

            contactName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
        }

        cursor.close();

        Log.d(TAG, "Contact Name: " + contactName);

    }
```

More detail refer below link https://tausiq.wordpress.com/2012/08/23/android-get-contact-details-id-name-phone-photo/

Comment: Why is it `if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {`? Thanks]

Comment: I think we only have one entry thats why we are using cursor movetofirst. First it will check is cursor is empty or not if not it will return data

Comment: is you  able to get the phonenumber name ?

Comment: No because it is the same code that I provided in the question.

Comment: have you check number has name ?

Comment: change your line   int NameColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME); with  contactName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

Comment: Yay, it works. Why did that change it? Isn't it saying the same thing? Please let me know why this works

Comment: have a look there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8431897/get-first-and-last-name-of-a-contact-rather-than-single-display-name. you need to use genric data :)

Comment: also there http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Data.html and http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.html

Comment: Thank you Anjali, I read it, but I still don't understand why the two are different. Could you explain please? Thanks!

Comment: replace this line Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contactUri, null, null, null, null);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102057/discussion-between-anjali-tripathi-and-ruchir-baronia).

Comment: you need to apply some filter there inshort need to request the query as here say Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, other_query_params_for_filtering);